# Magento - Add Hidden Field to Contact Form

Tags: magento

I've been getting occasional spam coming from the contact form in my Magento store.  I am reluctant to add Captcha so would like to try adding a hidden field to the form.  If the field gets filled out then the form won't be submitted (most bots automatically complete all fields).

I know how to add the field but does anyone know how/where to add the code to reject the form if the field has a value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to know the controller action being requested by your contacts form. If you don't know it yet, check the `action` param of your `<form>`, or use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com), or use some browser specific tool (like Firebug, etc.) to find out.

Next, [override](http://www.catgento.com/how-to-override-a-magento-core-controller/) the found controller action by your own.

Finally, in your overridden action, put

```
$sMyHiddenField = $this->getRequest()->getParam('my_hidden_field', '');
if ($sMyHiddenField) {
    $this->_forward('noRoute');    // or whatever
}
```

to catch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're going for here but maybe this will help.

The standard controller is `Mage_Contacts_IndexController` and it is located here: **app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php**

Of course you would either want to copy it to the `local` directory or extend the class with your own custom module. You could try using a copy of this file. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

My minor contribution for people searching - this kind of defence is called a honeypot. So there you go.

In Magento 1.3.2, I added this at line 75 of my copy of the controller at `code/local/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php`:

```
// check the spam honeypot
if (!empty($post['yummy'])) {
    $error = true;
}
```

Where 'yummy' is the hidden field I added in `template/contacts/form.phtml`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can put hidden fields while you create your form in the main block like this :

```
$fieldset->addField('entity_type_id', 'hidden', array(
      'name'               => 'entity_type_id',
      'value'              => 11
));
```

and after this you can check it in the saveAction() to check if these value are set or not